# Java: Replace all matching substrings of a string with their hashes

Tags: java, regex, replace, substring

I would like to replace all matching substrings of a string with a hashing of them.

Lets say I have a string like this

```
String myString = "This is a A1B4F string with some 342BF matches FFABC that should be replaced.";
```

And now I would like to replace all the matching strings to regex (for example here "([a-fA-F\d]{5})" ) with their hashed value.

Assume that there is a sting method that gets as a parameter the substring and returns its sha1 value

```
public static String giveMeTheSha1Of(String myClearText){
    return ....; (the sha1 value of the string)
}
```

How can I find all the matching substrings, and replace them with their hash?

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Look into the `Matcher` class. You will a two relevant methods to be used here.

Comment: `find`, `appendReplacement`, `appendTail`.

Comment: I have not developed a solution till now, but the only thing that I could thing, is braking the string into "words" and rebuilding it (if a word matches i would replace it)

Comment: Can you give some desired input and output values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Rohit Jain and Marko Topolnik. With your comments I found what I was searching for.

```
public static String replace5CharHex(String input){

    String REGEX = "([a-fA-F\\d]{5})";
    String tmpSubstring = "";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {

        tmpSubstring = hashManager.createNewHash(m.group());
        m.appendReplacement(sb, tmpSubstring);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    return sb.toString();

}
```